# Prior for df in a multivariate t-distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, t-distribution

I'm working on a robust bayesian regression with a multivariate response.

Right now i'm trying to set prior distribution for degrees of freedom of multivariate t-distribution

I read here https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations that a choice would be a gamma( it's referred to univariate case) while `LaplacesDemon` package examples (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaplacesDemon/vignettes/Examples.pdf) suggestS an half cauchy.

Does Anyone have some reference to deal with it? or any useful tips to decide.

Thanks

Comment: You could try this https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1393251776